# Javascript - Replacing a value located between a boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have the string 
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

I want to use "The" as a left boundary and "dog" as a right boundary and replace everything in between with a space so that it returns:

"The dog"

I sort of know how to replace a specified string with a substitute value, but I do not know how to replace something in between boundaries. Do I need to do some sort of Regular expression? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a regular expression that matches *The anything dog*.

Comment: Yes, use a regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Another option: convert the string to an array (str.split()). Then, you can manipulate the string the way you want. Finally, you use a join() and your string is ready. Remember that strings are imutable.

Comment: You can do `str.slice(0, indexOfThe + lengthOfThe) + str.slice(indexOfDog)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The regex you would use is `(The).+?(dog)`

The string operation would look like this:

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
var result = str.replace(/(The).+?(dog)/, "$1 $2");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I actually don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks for this :) Very helpful. p.s I did not downvote you.

Comment: If this answers your question as you were looking for, you can click the check mark next to it so that people will know it answered your question, or perhaps wait until people justify their downvotes, but they seem to have hit and run.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this seems extremely limiting. What happens when the delimiters change? Or the pattern? At least implement regex matching to return the matched values, making it bit more abstract

Comment: @lux I'm not sure what's so extreme about it, but I'll go for being more abstract since it means the answer might be helpful for people with similar questions. If the pattern changes, then make the regex the parameter of some function. If it needs to be more robust, perhaps some word-boundary assertions could be used: `\b(The)\b.+?\b(dog)\b`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any string:

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
console.log(s.replace(/^(.+?) (.+) (.+)$/,'$1 $3'))
```

If you want to use specific delimiters instead of the first and last words, use:

```
s.replace(/(The) (.+) (dog)/,'$1 $3')
```

Where "The" and "dog." would be any delimiters you want. If you try, for instance:

```
s.replace(/(fox) (.+) (over)/,'$1 $3')
```

It will return:

> The quick brown fox over the lazy dog.

Comment: This works, but the OP is looking to use specific delimiters, not necessary just to remove everything except for the first and last word.

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me.

var string="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

string =string.replace(/("The")(.+?)(?="dog")/," ");

Comment: Really? Because the result is `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."`, which is not what you wanted. Even removing the quotes doesn't produce the output you want.